# how can I test logic under the condition of "'ontouchstart' in window" in JS

Tags: javascript

We have some logic under "ontouchstart in window". We use popup form for the desktop website, the rest of cases is to show normal form.

```
 var isDesktopDevice = !('ontouchstart' in window);

 if (isDesktopDevice) {
        //popup form
 } else {
        //normal form
 }
```

I wonder how can I test it in javascript

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not really into touchstart, but I believe this article can help you out https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/

Comment: Test some logic... what logic? Note that some laptops/monitors have touchscreen support, so I don't know what exactly you're going to test...

Comment: Override isDesktopDevice in your tests. Worry about the outcome of the code, not wether ('ontouchstart' in window) works.